# How to use java -cp command in Ant?

Tags: command-line, ant

I have some jar files which are added in the CLASS_PATH of the batch process.So at the end of the batch process all I have to do is just to use java command shown below

> java -cp %CLASS_PATH% com.web.MainClass arg1

I am planning to do the same thing using Ant. Any suggestion of how my target should look like?

Answer (score 4):

You use the `<java>` Ant target.  See [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

For example:

```
<java classname="com.web.MainClass">
  <arg value="arg1"/>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="..."/>
    <pathelement location="..."/>
  </classpath>
</java>
```